# Do Kindles get firmware updates?

Tags: kindle, firmware

Hello =) The title says it all: do Kindles ever get firmware updates? I've had issues on my Kindle that went away on their own and a friend suggested it might be due to a firmware / software (not sure what the correct term is?) update that introduced a bug that was removed in the next update. But that would only be possible if there are updates to begin with =)
I have a 4th gen basic Kindle if that's relevant.
Thank you ^^

Comment: Why not jailbreak it? http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=161284

Comment: Because I don't want to get out of the easy system if I can avoid it. In the end I got a new Kindle so problem solved ^^ but thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do!

In fact at [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200774090) page you can find the update for your kindle (if it's not a kindle touch, then it's called kindle 5th generation), with the following information (bold is supplied):

> We have a new, free software update available for your Kindle (5th Generation). **This update automatically downloads and installs on your Kindle when connected wirelessly**; however, you can also manually download the software and transfer the update to your device via USB cable.

This means that, yes, it is possible that your Kindle automatically updated itself downloading the new firmware online.

Comment: Thank you ^^ However, I just checked and my Kindle isn't 5th gen, it's 4th gen, and the Kindle 4 isn't on the list. :/

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it isn't on the list, but checking the images that Amazon gives to recognize your device (https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=201263790), I found the Kindle 4th generation image under the Kindle 5th generation name... I don't know the reason, but probably they are so similar that they decided to consider them as the same device. Really, they go up to the Kindle 1st generation, so for sure they didn't forget the 4th one!