# Upgrade Kindle 4 system from 4.1.3 to 5.6

Tags: kindle

I haven't found a way to upgrade the system of my old Kindle 4 notouch. I also have a Kindle Paperwhite and its interface is very nice, and has a great addition: vocabulary cards made from those words looked up in the dictionary.

Is there a way to perform that upgrade manually, or will Amazon in one day offer that to those devices?

Comment: Kindle 4 notouch?

Comment: Kindle 4th generation, the non touch version.

Answer (score 1):

The [firmware update page](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_bc_nav?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200529680) of Kindle does not list Kindle 4th generation notouch. Accoring to [this](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/6329/91) answer and [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=201263790), your kindle is listed under 5th generation.

The latest firmware version number for the Kindle 5th generation is [4.1.3](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_navbox_top_kindle4?nodeId=200774090) so you cannot update it to 5.6.0.